# Chrome - SSL Security issue on Windows platforms?

Tags: security, google-chrome, browser, encryption, ssl

[Fortify.net](https://www.fortify.net/cgi/ssl_2.pl) is a service that displays what's the currently encryption key used by your browser in a https connection.
If I browse this site with Chrome 4.1.249.1042 in WinXp SP3 the key used is

> RC4 cipher, 128-bit key

This encryption is weak, and it's the one used by old browsers like IE6.

Chrome works fine on Fedora9 and it uses

> AES cipher, 256-bit key

as more modern browsers do (i.e.Firefox)

I consider this a security issue. I'm considering to switch back to Firefox in Windows.
Do you know if it's possible to change the default encryption key in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

> I consider this a security issue

Why?

According to the very site you are linking to :

> This is a high-grade encryption
>   connection, regarded by most experts
>   as being suitable for sending or
>   receiving even the most sensitive or
>   valuable information across a network.

Also, on my xp machine, both Opera 10 and IE 8 (neither of which can be considered old browers) show RC4 cipher, 128-bit key

On windows 7

```
 Chrome (5.0.366.2) - AES cipher, 128-bit key
 IE8                - AES cipher, 128-bit key
 FireFox            - AES cipher, 256-bit key
```

Firefox on xp also shows AES cipher, 256-bit key.

> Do you know if it's possible to change the default encryption key in Chrome?

I think Chrome, Opera and IE8 all use the encryption built into the Operating system, whereas Firefox wrote their own. (I could be wrong, as this is a mixture of rumour and guesswork). So it might be a case of finding out if you can update your encryption level in your operating system.

Comment: I consider it a security issue because as I read on Wikipedia RC4 128-bit can be hacked and because AES-256 is considered more secure than RC4. Maybe I'm wrong. .. btw I consider IE9 old already

Comment: I'm no security expert, but I took the articles I read on RC4/AES to mean that some implementations of RC4 (eg WEP) were very bad and were insecure in real-life, but other implementations are 'secure enough'. Given the scramble to replace WEP when it was discovered that it could be cracked, I would have expected Microsoft to have been forced (by big corporations still using XP) to update the encryption in XP if it could be exploited in real-life.

There was talk a while back about chrome switching to use the firefox encryption libraries, so it is possible things might change.